# Contour finding

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I want to detect an area(LCD screen) that contains several digital numbers, what I am trying to do is:
1. use cvCanny() to convert the image to edge image,
2. use cvFindContours() to detect the contour, here I am using the TREE mode
3. detect every contour and its number of children, if the number of children is larger than a certain number, combined with the contour area and the aspect ratio, that is the area I am interested in.
My problem is I am using the for(;contours!=NULL;contours=contours->h_next) loop, but I am only able to get the most top level of the tree and its direct number of children, the rest seems not included by this way, is there anyway that I can get through every contour and get everyone's number of children?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is `contours->v_next`. It is used to access child contours of a contour. `h_next` is used to iterate contours on the same level. Probably you already guessed *h* stands for *horizontal* and *v* stands for *vertical*.

Of course, when using `cvFindContours()` be sure to use it with `CV_RETR_TREE` method to get contours in a tree fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I know v_next, but how to handle it on my problem? Suppose I got 10 different images, I cant go through the tree one by one.

Comment: You can loop on v_next->h_next and count the children. Because they are pointers looping is a cheap operation, do not worry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I just have one more thing to make sure,for h_next and h_prev, these two can only link sequences that have the same parent, right? If two children from two different parents, they cannot be used by h_next, right?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Maybe you should look at tree traversal methods: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal